# find xpath using selenium

Tags: selenium, xpath

I need to find friends list of names of Facebook, for that i need to catch "name" button (or tab) after logged in. How can i catch that one using x path. And what i did is left click on code and clicked on "copyxpath" option using firebug. But it works. I am using java, web-driver...Thanks in advance...

My code is:

```
@Test
      public void testUntitled2() throws Exception {
        driver.get(baseUrl + "/");
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("email")).sendKeys("smallfishhh4@gmail.com");
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).clear();
        driver.findElement(By.id("pass")).sendKeys("password");
        driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_n")).click();
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/a/span)).click();
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Friends336")).click();
      }
```

Comment: Facebook offers a stable, easy to use and robust API. Don't scrape their site, it changes often and will break screen parsing.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to click the facebook username tab link in the header then try:

```
//span[@class='headerTinymanName']
```

Instead of:

```
/html/body/div/div/div/div/div/div/div/ul/li/a/span
```

you should take advantage of classnames etc. whenever possible when using xpath. The xpath tools sometimes produce silly xpaths. In my facebook this tab link had the class `headerTinymanName`, so selecting by this name should work for you.

Alternatively you could do it without xpath as well by using: `By.className("headerTinymanName")`

BTW: also try to avoid selecting links by linktext, especially if the linktext will be something that frequently changes, so try to select this link by class or id as well:

```
driver.findElement(By.linkText("Friends336")).click();
```

Comment: Re. Selecting by linktext;  I think to say avoid using linktext selectors is a little presumptive. The range of selectors are all valid when used in the right context. Saying that linktext often changes is making assumptions about sivea's application. Every application is different and different approaches are valid. Imagine a test where you create a record, then select that record from a list. It may be that the only way to select that record is by the name you gave it in the creation. If so, then by linktext is a perfectly valid approach.

Comment: In his case the link text seems to contain the friends count. So if fb user deletes or adds a friend the linktext changes. @RobbieWareham

Comment: Thank you donfuxx, i was stopped at driver.findElement(By.id("u_0_n")).click(); so plz guide me

Comment: well, for me the fb login button had id `u_0_l` so that id seems to vary (maybe they test different styles or something like that). Try an xpath like: `//label[@id='loginbutton']/input`

Comment: try to find elements/attributes that are unlikely to change and that are descriptive. `u_0_n` wasn't very descriptive and looks like there is an a-b test or something like that active

Comment: hi donfuxx20,  how can i catch friends list of any facebook account, i came up to see friends list by using java, webdriver, selenium. Thanks in advance.......